# Application Cache Error event: Failed to commit new cache to storage

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, storage, manifest

I've created a website offline Application Cache and it works well in most cases, but for some users it fails. In Chrome, when I launch the website, it loads the manifest and when I need to create the cache, it displays the error: "Application Cache Error event: Failed to commit new cache to storage".
When I try to start the Application with the Icognito-Mode (Privat Chrome Navigation) it work again... so i don't know what to do.

Chrome 86 is released, but we still see the error on some (not all) computers. Can someone help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your application cache might be broken. Try clearing it but entering the following to address bar:

```
chrome://appcache-internals/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried it and this is the result:
Application Cache
Instances in: C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default (0)

It's empty :/